# Sending parameters to Web Service on Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-services

I have a text field and a button, when user click the button the text on text field gonna be sended to a web service which expects a post parameter called 'nomTipus'. on the [Angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post) it's not told how to set name to the parameters

> post(url, data, [config]);

What I'm missing? I shouldn't use named paramaters on a web service? It's my first try under Angular.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
post(url, data, [config]);
```

In data part you can send Json objects for example

```
data = {
  "name" : "Amit",
   "age" : 24
}
```

In your case if your textField model is **$scope.textField** then data will be -

```
data = {
   "nomTipus" : $scope.textField
}
```

Comment: I'm not in front of computer now (so I can't try it), but If the web services just expect a post parameter called nomTipus if I send a JSON object this will run?

Comment: Finally I discart to use a Web Service to save this text field value I added this field to another working form. Thanks anyway. Regards.

Comment: Welcome, always there to help.